# Formula to remove row with empty column and select specific columns in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following scenario.

```
Driving Toyota      Hilux     Best
Driving Mitsubishi  Triton
Driving Ford        Ranger    Good


Driving Hilux   Best    
Driving Ranger  Good
```

I would like to use a formula to automatically rearrange the upper table to the lower table.
I was actually trying to eliminate all rows with empty cell in fourth column and then remove the second column.
What formula should I use ?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In A6, copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$D,MMULT(SMALL(($D$1:$D$3="")/1%%+ROW($1:$3),ROWS($1:1)),1),INDEX({1,3,4},COLUMN(A1)))&"","")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per below screenshot use following formula to `A6` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$3,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$3)/($D$1:$D$3<>""),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

[image]

> You need to change `Column` reference of `INDEX()` formula for 2nd and 3rd column as you want to skip `B Column`. So, for cell `B6` formula will be...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$3,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$3)/($D$1:$D$3<>""),ROW(1:1)),3),"")
```

If you notice `Column` argument is `3` here because we skip `column 2` of your source data.